# Funny sound under the gear, after it hits the stone

Tags: honda, noise, jazz

My car is a honda jazz its an automatic and  the is a  funny sound under the gear, its like something is loose, especially when it idle, and when it reverse but when you put on (D) Drive it stops, Can you kindly please assist me what to do.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Funny how ? Is it like zzzzzzzzzzz
Or ter teer tr tr terr ?

Comment: It's like terrrrrrr I was suspecting the exsozo... But it's not loose it's fine